# Smoothing an airfoil data

Tags: matlab

These are some data points for an airfoil shape:

```
x=[1 0.8518 0.7040 0.5536 0.3988 0.2454 0.0937 0.0199 0.0015 0 0.0169 0.0812 0.2054 0.3525 0.4979 0.6457 0.7974 0.9497];
y=[0 0.0355 0.0819 0.1206 0.1347 0.1200 0.0777 0.0363 0.0162 0 -0.0197 -0.0428 -0.0645 -0.0749 -0.0701 -0.0506 -0.0249 -0.0026];
```

I'm not allowed to use any curve fitting toolbox. What method do I use to plot a smoother looking airfoil shape. Should I use polyfit or interp1?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `interp1` should do the job, but you need to spilt your data in two halves, the positive `y` and the negative `y`, with their corresponding `x` values.

Here's an example using cubic interpolation. Check the [doc for `interp1`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for more details:

```
ypos = y(y>=0);    % y only when positive
xpos = x(y>=0);    % corresponding values of x
yneg = y(y<0);     % y only when strictly negative
xneg = x(y<0);     % corresponding values of x
xi=linspace(0,max(x),100);                      % values of x for interpolation (100 values linearly spaced between 0 and the max of x
yposi = interp1(xpos,ypos,xi,'cubic','extrap'); % interpolated values of y (when positive) using cubic interpolation and extrapolation
ynegi = interp1(xneg,yneg,xi,'cubic','extrap'); % interpolated values of y (when strictly negative) using cubic interpolation and extrapolation
plot(x,y,'ro',xi,yposi,'b-',xi,ynegi,'b-')      % plot interpolated data on top of original data
```